# Spark withColumn - add column using non-Column type variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I add a column to a data frame from a variable value?

I know that I can create a data frame using `.toDF(colName)` and that `.withColumn` is the method to add the column. But, when I try the following, I get a type mismatch error:

```
val myList = List(1,2,3)
val myArray = Array(1,2,3)

myList.toDF("myList")
  .withColumn("myArray", myArray)
```

> Type mismatch, expected: Column, actual: Array[Int]

This compile error is on `myArray` within the `.withColumn` call. How can I convert it from an Array[Int] to a Column type?

Answer (score 2):

The error message has exactly what is up, you need to input a column (or a `lit()`) as the second argument as `withColumn()`

try this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.typedLit

val myList = List(1,2,3)
val myArray = Array(1,2,3)

myList.toDF("myList")
  .withColumn("myArray", typedLit(myArray))
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure `withColumn` is what you're actually seeking.  You could apply `lit()` to make myArray conform to the method specs, but the result will be the same array value for every row in the DataFrame:

```
myList.toDF("myList").withColumn("myArray", lit(myArray)).
  show
// +------+---------+
// |myList|  myArray|
// +------+---------+
// |     1|[1, 2, 3]|
// |     2|[1, 2, 3]|
// |     3|[1, 2, 3]|
// +------+---------+
```

If you're trying to merge the two collections column-wise, it's a different transformation from what `withColumn` offers.  In that case you'll need to convert each of them into a DataFrame and combine them via a `join`.

Now if the elements of the two collections are row-identifying and match each other pair-wise like in your example and you want to join them that way, you can simply join the converted DataFrames:

```
myList.toDF("myList").join(
    myArray.toSeq.toDF("myArray"), $"myList" === $"myArray"
  ).show
// +------+-------+
// |myList|myArray|
// +------+-------+
// |     1|      1|
// |     2|      2|
// |     3|      3|
// +------+-------+
```

But in case the two collections have elements that aren't join-able and you simply want to merge them column-wise, you'll need to use compatible row-identifying columns from the two dataframes to join them.  And if there isn't such row-identifying columns, one approach would be to create your own `rowId`s, as in the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df1 = List("a", "b", "c").toDF("myList")
val df2 = Array("x", "y", "z").toSeq.toDF("myArray")

val rdd1 = df1.rdd.zipWithIndex.map{
  case (row: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ id)
}
val df1withId = spark.createDataFrame( rdd1,
  StructType(df1.schema.fields :+ StructField("rowId", LongType, false))
)

val rdd2 = df2.rdd.zipWithIndex.map{
  case (row: Row, id: Long) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ id)
}
val df2withId = spark.createDataFrame( rdd2, 
  StructType(df2.schema.fields :+ StructField("rowId", LongType, false))
)

df1withId.join(df2withId, Seq("rowId")).show
// +-----+------+-------+
// |rowId|myList|myArray|
// +-----+------+-------+
// |    0|     a|      x|
// |    1|     b|      y|
// |    2|     c|      z|
// +-----+------+-------+
```